# Can not get methods on instantiated class

Tags: javascript, class

I have this class definition , create instances but can not get methods inside class definition.

```
export class Partner {
  constructor (instructorPeer, id) {
    this.instructorPeer = instructorPeer;
    this.id = id;
    this.basePath = `/partners/${this.id}`;
  }

  async call (path, params) {
    return this.instructorPeer.call (
      `/partners/${this.id}/methods/${path}`,
      params
    );
  }
```

This code is from another file which creates objects with partner class. I create objects wit new partner

Why there is no method on returned newPartner object ? How can I reach that cal method then ?

```
const partners = {chrome: [], firefox: [], safari: [], ie: []};

const self = this;
const appropriatePartners = await this.retrievePartners (partnerInfo);
```

async createSession (partnerInfo) {
    const partners = {chrome: [], firefox: [], safari: [], ie: []};

```
const self = this;
const appropriatePartners = await this.retrievePartners (partnerInfo);
Object.keys (appropriatePartners).forEach (function (key) {
  appropriatePartners[key].forEach (partner => {
    let newPartner = [new Partner (self.instructorPeer, partner.id)];
    partners[key].push (newPartner);
  });
});

return new Session (partners);
```

}

And this is also another file which uses objects returned from there.

```
const partners = await getTestPartners (capabilities);
partners.chrome[0].call ('connect', myparams);
```

Comment: is `newPartner` suppose to be an array?

Comment: What is your problem with the code?

Comment: key == "chrome" ??

Comment: new Partner is an object. partners objects holds different sub objects and each one is an array so, -> partners.chrome[0] is an array

Comment: Bergi problem is, parterns.chrome[0] object does not have any methods, it was initialized from partner class.